# Haskell time measurment

Tags: haskell

I have the following matrix multiplication function

```
winograd :: M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int -> M.Matrix Int
winograd a b = c
where
  ra = M.nrows a
  ca = M.ncols a
  rb = M.nrows b
  cb = M.ncols b

  isEven = even ca

  avs = V.generate ra $ \i -> M.getRow (i+1) a
  bvs = V.generate cb $ \j -> M.getCol (j+1) b

  rows = V.generate ra $ \i -> wgdGroup $ V.unsafeIndex avs i
  cols = V.generate cb $ \j -> wgdGroup $ V.unsafeIndex bvs j

  wgdGroup x = let
                 finish = (V.length x - 1)
               in
                 forLoopFold 0 (<finish) (+2) 0 $
                 \acc i -> acc
                 - V.unsafeIndex x i *  V.unsafeIndex x (i+1)

  c = if isEven then
        M.matrix ra cb $
        \(i,j) ->
        V.unsafeIndex rows (i-1) +
        V.unsafeIndex cols (j-1)  +
        g (V.unsafeIndex avs (i-1)) (V.unsafeIndex bvs (j-1))
      else
        M.matrix ra cb $
        \(i,j) ->
        V.unsafeIndex rows (i-1) +
        V.unsafeIndex cols (j-1) +
        g (V.unsafeIndex avs (i-1)) (V.unsafeIndex bvs (j-1)) +
        V.last (V.unsafeIndex avs (i-1)) * V.last (V.unsafeIndex bvs (j-1))

  g r c = forLoopFold 0 (<(ca-1)) (+2) 0 $ \acc i ->
            let
              x1 = V.unsafeIndex r i
              x2 = V.unsafeIndex r (i+1)
              y1 = V.unsafeIndex c i
              y2 = V.unsafeIndex c (i+1)
            in
            acc + (x1+y2)*(x2+y1)
```

And I measure the execution time of this function as follows, using `clock` and `formatting` packages (yes, I know about Criterion, but now I need to measure it this way):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = simple 2 (-1) 1000
  let b = simple 2 (-3) 1000
  start <- getTime Realtime
  let
    c = winograd a b
  end <- c `deepseq` getTime Realtime
  fprint (timeSpecs % "\n") start end
```

where `simple` is

```
simple :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M.Matrix Int
simple x y size = M.matrix size size $ \(i,j) -> x*i+y*j
```

I get the result about 5 seconds. But when I get rid of the function `simple` and do like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = M.matrix 1000 1000 $ \(i,j) -> 2*i-1*j
  let b = M.matrix 1000 1000 $ \(i,j) -> 2*i-3*j
  start <- getTime Realtime
  let
    c = winograd a b
  end <- c `deepseq` getTime Realtime
  fprint (timeSpecs % "\n") start end
```

the time increases to 15 seconds!

Very interesting why. Compiled with flag -O2.

Comment: Try `deepseq` to force creation of matrices `a` & `b` before `start <- ...` in above examples.

Comment: @freestyle It helps, but I wonder why this increases the time? Is it laziness, or optimization, or something else?

Comment: Your code looks like: "Hey, compiler/runtime, create matrices when you want." And this they do. Why, I don't known. But I know it's compiler dependent code.